# How to Bulk Query Total Number of Commits Across An Azure DevOps Organization

Tags: git, azure-devops, reporting

We are looking to generate some organization-wide reports to show the total usage of our Azure DevOps organization. I've been able to generate this for total numbers of projects and work items, but I haven't found a way to query things like total number of repos, total number of branches, total number of commits, or total number of pull requests.

There are in-built reports on the home page of a project that shows some of these stats for that project, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this across all projects. Any assistance would be appreciated if anyone knows more!

Comment: How are you generating this report?  Is it something native in Azure DevOps, like a dashboard?

Comment: It wouldn't matter as long as I can gather the data. For work items, I was able to use odata as described in the below link. DevOps does have a default native report on each project that displays commit history for that project on the default Project Overview page, but it doesn't appear to be extendable to view all projects at once. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/aggregated-data-analytics?view=azure-devops

Comment: If you just need to gather the data you could write a Powershell script that iterates over each project and adds the totals.  Would that work?

Comment: Sure, that could work. Is there an easy way to do that? I believe that the commit counting can only be done by individual repo, so I'm not quite sure how to iterate between all the projects. (sorry for asking this, I'm not very tech savvy so I'm mostly just trying to find documentation that I can copy and it would work)

Comment: It looks like you can pull a list of repos in a project https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP and pull a list of all commits in a repo https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP, but I don't know how to merge these together cleanly or how to pull a list of all projects automatically.